# how to convert model to xml in asp .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap

I tried to get response by calling [this API](http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso).

This was the request xml code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ListOfLanguagesByName xmlns="http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo">
        </ListOfLanguagesByName>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but I could not get this exact from my model.
I got the following response

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Body />
</Envelope>
```

my model is

```cs
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "tLanguage", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
public class TLanguage
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sISOCode", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
    public string SISOCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sName", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
    public string SName { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ListOfLanguagesByNameResult", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
public class ListOfLanguagesByNameResult
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "tLanguage", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
    public List<TLanguage> TLanguage { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ListOfLanguagesByNameResponse", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
public class ListOfLanguagesByNameResponse
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ListOfLanguagesByNameResult", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
    public ListOfLanguagesByNameResult ListOfLanguagesByNameResult { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "m", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string M { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "soap:Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ListOfLanguagesByNameResponse", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
    public ListOfLanguagesByNameResponse ListOfLanguagesByNameResponse { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "soap:Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
public class Envelope
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "soap:Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Soap { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ListOfLanguagesByName", Namespace = "http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo")]
public class ListOfLanguagesByName
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
public class RequestEnvelope
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
    public Body Body { get; set; } = new Body();
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsi { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xsd { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soap12", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Soap12 { get; set; }
}
```

I used `https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/` to convert xml to c#.

my code is

```cs
try
{
    RequestEnvelope objRequestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope();
    string str = string.Empty;
    var client = new RestClient("http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso");
    client.Timeout = -1;
    XmlSerializer objXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(objRequestEnvelope.GetType());
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    };
    using (var sww = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, settings))
        {
            objXmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, objRequestEnvelope);
            str = sww.ToString(); // Your XML
        }
    }
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
    request.AddParameter("application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8", str, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    Envelope objEnvelope = new Envelope();
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(response.Content);
    objEnvelope = (Envelope)objXmlSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);

    await requestDetail.RequestAddEdit(objRequestParameterInfo, objAfterUserLogin);
    return Ok();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to handcraft a SOAP request? Why don't you use some built-in tool?

Comment: how to implement that??
i am new here..so can u gove some example?

Comment: Visual Studio can generate SOAP service client from a wsdl file. In your case the wsdl is located [here](http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso?WSDL). And [here](https://www.toptip.ca/2014/06/create-soap-client-from-wsdl-with.html) is a a short tutorial with step-by-step instructions how you can generate a SOAP client.

Comment: okay..will try it..thank you for ur answer

Comment: Have you succeeded with that approach?

Comment: If it worked fine then please feel free to post an answer where you describe how did you solve it.